# AudioSystem successfully plays Clip, but only once - LineUnavailableException

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, javasound

I'm using below Java code to play a sound on a USB sound card on my Raspberry PI:

```
try {
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(someBinaryData));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(someMixerInfo);
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
} catch(Exception exc) {
   // debug stuff
}
```

and it works just fine - but only once. When I try to play a sound again, I'm getting an exception:

> javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.

The exception is thrown regardless if I want to replay the clip, or play a different one.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to play multiple sounds simultaneously, overlapping each other.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replay the `Clip`, the usual way is to set the frame position back to 0, then call start.

The `Clip` should probably be an instance variable that you only load once, and hold in memory.

```
Clip clip;

public void loadClip() {
    clip = ...
}

public void play() {
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}
```

IDK exactly why your code won't play the second time. Perhaps one of the lines is tied up somehow and needs releasing before it can be used again. Usually `AudioInputStreams` are closed when one is done with them. Maybe that is related what is throwing the exception. But it is not clear to me, as it looks like you are creating an entirely new instance.

Comment: The exception is thrown not only when trying to replay the `Clip`, but also when trying to play an entirely different one. Also, how should I go about releasing the line? Lastly, ideal situation would be if I could play several different clips at once, overlapping each other, instead of waiting for one to finish.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hot link to a sound file if possible, or generate one at run-time (e.g. a simple sin wave).

Comment: Agreeing with Andrew Thompson, an MRE would be helpful. @mag_zbc I am unable to intelligently respond to your comment as there is no new info and it did not indicate whether the position resetting described was tried. As to multiple clip playbacks, please distinguish if you wish to play the same Clip/Sound effect concurrently, or if this problem exists with concurrent unique sounds. If the latter, mixing to a single output may be required, as provided by TinySound or AudioCue libraries on github. AudioCue also allows concurrent playback of individual Clips and is modeled on the Clip.

Comment: The problem with being unable to play any Clip again was solved by adding a line listener and freeing the line, but what really did the trick was your AudioCue library, which does exactly what I need.

Comment: Very gratifying to hear! You are the first person I know who is using it with the Raspberry PI. Cool to hear it works there. Would love to hear more about your project sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Clip#play()`, I advise you to use `Clip#loop(int)`. For example:

```
clip.loop(0); //will play the clip once, you can play it again by calling loop(0) again
clip.loop(1); //will play, and play one more time after the clip ends (loops once)
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINOUSLY); //will play forever.
```

Also, make sure you play each clip in a different `Thread`.